# How to edit files in docker for scrapinghub portia

Tags: python, docker, docker-container, portia, scrapinghub

I have created a pipeline to store the crawled items in JSON file and added the pipeline to the path `/slybot/slybot/mypipeline.py`

After that I have installed Portia package using docker. Installation successful.
Then I have started portia using the command which is given in the installation document page
 `docker run -i -t --rm -v <PROJECT_FOLDER>/data:/app/slyd/data:rw -p 9001:9001 --name portia portia`

I am able to load portia in my browser. And I have created a spider.
When I try to run the spider, I encountered a mistake in my pipeline file.

Now I want to edit that file and fix the mistake.

I have tried to copy the pipeline from the container to local host and edited that again copied the same to container by referring the [docker copy page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/).

But when I again run the command 
 `docker run -i -t --rm -v <PROJECT_FOLDER>/data:/app/slyd/data:rw -p 9001:9001 --name portia portia` and create a spider and tried to run that spider. And it seems the pipeline file is not updated.

I found that every time when I run the portia run command, new container is creating and now I am thinking that editing that pipeline file in a container will not work for me. Am I correct?

How can I edit the pipeline file alone in the docker without building portia again in docker?

Comment: It looks like there's a web interface for creating projects, is there also one for editing them?

Comment: Do you mean creating spider through Portia? But I just want to edit the file in docker

Comment: If you think it's easier, there are a few options, I can add those as an answer. I just wanted to make sure that's the best way to approach the problem.

Comment: Yes, you shall provide the solution and I check that from my end